# Work with Controls in panel, edit picturebox controls, only

Tags: c#, controls

panel1 has multiple pictureBoxes and labels.

I want to make a button that will change the style of picturebox controls only.

```
 private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (PictureBox pb in panel1.Controls)
            {                
                if (pb is PictureBox)
                {
                    cnt++;
                    //do stuff
                    excludelist1.Add(pb.Name);
                    //clickedPictureBox.Hide();                        
                    pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                    pb.Tag = Color.Blue;
                }
            }
            label1.Text = "Exclusded Count = " + cnt;    
        }
```

//Above code gives me 'unable to cast label from panel' error.
How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panel contains multiple `Control` types, not just `PictureBox`es. Change your loop as follows:

```
foreach (var pb in panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
   cnt++;
   //do stuff 
   excludelist1.Add(pb.Name); 
   //clickedPictureBox.Hide(); 
   pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
   pb.Tag = Color.Blue;
}
```

The `OfType<TResult>()` is an `IEnumerable` LINQ extension that will filter the `Controls` collection by the specified type - in your case, `PictureBox`. Since the collection is now filtered at the time `foreach` loop begins, you don't need the `if (pb is PictureBox)` statement - only `PictureBox`es will be looped through.

By the way, the reason that `if` statement didn't help you is because the `foreach` tried to cast a `Label` as a `PictureBox`, which caused an `InvalidCastException`, *before* your check had a chance to run. Technically, your approach can also work, just delay the cast operation until you know it's a `PictureBox`:

```cs
foreach (var control in panel1.Controls)
{ 
   if (control is PictureBox pb) 
   { 
      cnt++; 
      //do stuff 
      excludelist1.Add(pb.Name); 
      //clickedPictureBox.Hide(); 
      pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      pb.Tag = Color.Blue; 
   } 
}
```

Here's a link to the docs for the `OfType` method - I find that solution a bit more elegant, but either method works - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0